# Spring Data JPA set LocalDate format

Tags: spring, date, spring-data-jpa, jsr310

I'm trying to set `LocalDate` (and `LocalDateTime`) format in database like `dd-MM-yyyy` which is very useful sometimes. Instead I'm getting something like this in H2 DB.

`aced00057372000d6a6176612e74696d652e536572955d84ba1b2248b20c00007870770e05000007e1010c0e1c1837131f0078`

I tried to use `@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm")` but nothing changes.

```
@CreatedDate
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm")
private LocalDateTime created;
```

I'm using Spring MVC with Spring Data BOM Hopper-SR1 (1.10.1) and H2 DB 1.3.156

Comment: A date column has no format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added package to scan in configuration `@Bean` `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`

`entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.jpomykala.model", "org.springframework.data.jpa.convert.threeten");`

Now it's simple enough: 2017-01-12 14:55:42.238